# Distribute rabbitmq messages evenly

Tags: rabbitmq

At the moment we have number of publishers (micro-services) which publish their messages to exchange. Each message has a serviceId attribute. The queue is connected to a single subscriber (micro-service) which processes the queue messages, processing of a single message is a costly operation (takes about 20-30 secs).
Currently we have the following situation: service A publishes ~200 messages, after some seconds service B publishes 2 messages. So the subscriber will process these 2 messages only after the first 200 will be processed.

We want to process the messages in the order they came to the queue, but with respect to the source serviceId.

Obvious solution is to split the queue to a separate queues (one per publisher) and subscribe to each queue separately, but the number of publishers can change, we need to request them dynamically and subscribe (unsubscribe) to them.

Another approach is to replicate our subscriber app to have one to one relationship between publisher and subscriber, but this will require more system resources.

What would be the best approach to handle this situation?
Thanks!

Comment: See: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html
You are over-engineering your solution, RabbitMQ is meant to handle most of your custom solution's cases. Most of your problems seems to come from the fact that you use direct (pub-to-sub) messaging instead of leveraging exchanges (brokers).

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get your point, please clarify

Comment: You're using RabbitMQ incorrectly. Publishers and Subscribers are not supposed to know each others. You're trying to use it as a message queue subsystem where it is a messaging subsystem.

Comment: One way to solve your issue is having multiple subscribers on same queue but listening on different routingKey. If you have data about publisher serviceIds then that can be your routing-key, you have to figure unique routingkey between publisher and consumer. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html

Answer (score 0):

/!\ Be careful, publishers publish to an exchange, not to a queue.

> We want to process the messages in the order they came to the queue,
>   but with respect to the source serviceId.

If I understand well, you want to load balance your messages according to a serviceId, and serviceIds are not known in advance.

The solution I would suggest here is to have a direct exchange, with routing keys such as `xxxxx.<serviceId>`. Then, you can bind one queue by serviceId (that is: one queue for service A, one for service B, ...), each consumer consuming on all queues.

Then you have to handle the publisher subscription: I would make a publisher publish a "hello" message, this message being consumed by each consumer, which in turn bind a new queue for that service (using `xxxxx.<newServiceId>`), and finally publish a response back (so that the publisher can start sending messages).

Note: each service queue is the same for all consumers, resulting in the worker configuration (see [this tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html))

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, sorry. I mistyped it, of course we publish our messages to exchange.

Comment: I ended up with solution of having separate queue per serviceId, and in the subscriber app I request these queues from the admin application via http and subscribe to them.